# Simple way to add SVG images into a React project

Tags: reactjs, svg

I'm using file loader and can load pngs just fine. I'm doing `import myImage from "../../path/image.svg"` and then `<img src={myImage}/>`. When I use the developer tools and click on the SVG I'm trying to include, I get a page with a message like:

```
"Error on line 1 at column 1: Document is empty 

Below is a rendering of the page up to the first error."
```

Has anyone seen this error before and if so what can be done about it?

Comment: An svg is HTML, you can treat it like a conponent. No need to load it with a loader.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the file loader [docs](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/file-loader/) there is no mention of being able to load svg files.

You need to use a specialised loader. Here are webpack [docs](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/svg-inline-loader/) for one svg loader but there are plenty of others.

Answer (score 0):

I found out about [@svgr/webpack](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@svgr/webpack), with it you can import the SVGs like modules and then use them as components.